# How reload the helper once i change the values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, spacebars

Im trying to filter information in my page after the user select an option, so i made a "change" event and passed values ​​through the helper by sessions and its ok console log looks like the values passed ok, but it seems like the helper doesn't refresh or something because dont return the find with the new values, actually don't do anything, obviously there is something wrong, sorry for my ultra basic english, i hope you understand and help me, thanks for your time!

**Template**

```
<select id="mostrarTiposMenu" class="form-control">

        {{#each mostrarMenus}}
        <option value="{{nuevoTipoMenu}}" onchange="getMenu()">{{nuevoTipoMenu}}</option>
        {{/each}}
 </select>
```

**Events and helpers**

```
Template.main.events({
  "change #mostrarTiposMenu": function(evt) {
  var newValue = $(evt.target).val();
    Session.set("valueMenu", newValue);
    console.log("yo estoy en el event " + newValue);
  }
});


Template.main.helpers({  
 mostrarMenus : function(){
    return Menu.find();
  },
  mostrarPrimerDia: function(){
    var searchMenu = Session.get("valueMenu")
    console.log("Yo estoy en el helper " + searchMenu)
 var server = TimeSync.serverTime()
 var diaDeHoy = moment(server).locale("es").add(0,'days').format('dddd');
 return Promociones.find({'metadata.diaOferta' : { $in: [diaDeHoy] } },{'metadata.tipoMenu' : { $in: [searchMenu] } });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried using refresh option

```
$('selectmenu).refresh();
```